# Spring Cloud Data Flow - can it be used without spring boot?

Tags: spring, cloud

Can Spring Cloud Data Flow be used in Spring5 applications - NOT Spring Boot - my current employer seems to view Spring Boot applications as insecure (I've no idea why) in anyway I'd like to try use this stack for an integration project, so is it possible to use it without Spring Boot?

Comment: Yes, it's generally designed to work with Spring Boot - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#spring-cloud-stream-preface-creating-sample-application

Answer (score 0):

With Spring Cloud Data Flow you can deploy streams, tasks and batches.

This is all based on Spring, Spring Cloud and Spring Boot. Spring Boot is nothing else as a preconfigured Spring stack.

Spring Data Flow is a runitme that usually needs a cloud infrastructure like Kubernets.

I'm not sure if you really are looking for that or more for something like https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration